# My opened question was deleted, there was a link to another question I commented in. How can I find that question?

Tags: support, comments, search, deleted-questions

I already found that I can't find the question by my searching for my comment I made in it.

Maybe proceeding the other route, namely my deleted question? That wouldn't be easy, either.

Any way to find that question without asking for a new, similar question which gets downvoted because the topic already has a similar question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't search for comments easily, but you can look up *your* specific comments.

If you go to your user profile (click your name at the top, or on your user card), there is an activity tab among all of the other tabs on that page (summary is the default tab).  Selecting the activity tab will give you a list of all the actions you have taken on a site, with links to the respective posts.

Once you are looking at the actions tab, you can filter again by action type - in this case, you want to look at your comments.  Then, you'll see a list of all the comments you've made.  If the question you're looking for doesn't show up on this list, then that topic was probably deleted.

Comment: I have found it, thank you! Strangely, my comment in question does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the comments on data.stackexchange.com, which I believe is updated roughly weekly so that's your tool to find comments too old to easily find in the "activity" page on your profile.